# How do i work on multiple branches at the same time without commiting in Git?

Tags: git

It seems that whenever I change some files on one branch, and then want to change to a different branch to do some different work, the changes still come with me.  For example,

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
~/Sites/sc, kamilski81 (master) 
$ touch FakeFile
~/Sites/sc, kamilski81 (master) 
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   FakeFile
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
~/Sites/sc, kamilski81 (master) 
$ git checkout prod
Switched to branch 'prod'
~/Sites/sc, kamilski81 (prod) 
$ git status
# On branch prod
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   FakeFile
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

In this scenario why does the FakeFile come with me when i do a checkout to prod?  How can i edit multiple files on multiple branches without having to check them in yet?  Or am I just doing this completely incorrectly?

Comment: Git doesn't touch untracked files when switching branches. You will either have to commit the file along the current branch, or use a stash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git stash` on branch A to save the current state and check out the other branch, come back to A and use `git stash pop` to get to the state where you've left the branch. See the help page of git stash (`git help stash`) for more options on saving the local state with `git stash`

Comment: I don't think that would work for untracked files though, right? They'd have to be added first.

Comment: @katylavallee correct. `git stash` only applies to files that are under git's control